# How to open a split-diff for selected file out of the commit

Tags: plugin-fugitive

Using Vim-fugitive plugin I open a commit with

```
:Gedit HEAD~5
```

The buffer looks like this:

```
tree a75d4eea2207e408db6343a4869274b701b42135
parent 7fa89fec125ce60a341f7c37dd769a8a31c49359
author Takahiro Yoshihara <tacahiroy@gmail.com> Tue Feb 21 09:07:51 2017 +0900
committer Takahiro Yoshihara <tacahiroy@gmail.com> Sun Mar 19 18:16:51 2017 +0900

Fix incorrect matching in buffer mode with by_filename (#346)


diff --git a/autoload/ctrlp.vim b/autoload/ctrlp.vim
index 6558939..05196ae 100644
--- a/autoload/ctrlp.vim
+++ b/autoload/ctrlp.vim
@@ -2384,7 +2384,7 @@ endf
 fu! s:matchbuf(item, pat)
    let bufnr = s:bufnrfilpath(a:item)[0]
    let parts = s:bufparts(bufnr)
-   let item = bufnr.parts[0].parts[2].s:lash().parts[3]
+   let item = s:byfname ? parts[2] : bufnr.parts[0].parts[2].s:lash().parts[3]
    retu match(item, a:pat)
 endf
```

(the diff part appears folded)

Now putting the cursor on the first line of the diff, I would like to open that diff in a vertical split vim-diff mode like `:Gvdiff` (in a new tab or in the same tab below the current window) viewing the changes made to the file.

Currently issuing `:Gvdiff` compares the entire commit-buffer with something weird.

Basically I would like to have the same diff-view, as I get with `dv` in the `:Gstatus` window.

My questions are:

- How can I open the vertical split diff on a selected file?
- How can I close that view going back to my commit buffer?

Comment: I found, that with the simple `ENTER` opens the split diff view. But if closes the commit-edit buffer and there seams to be no way to open it again... (I have a mapping in place, that closes inactive fugitive-buffers)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `:h fugitive-mappings` you can use:

- `<cr>` to open the diff in the current window
- `o` open the diff in a horizontal split
- `O` to open the diff in a new tab page
- `S` open diff in a vertical split

I imagine you want to use `S` on the diff line. However as screen space can be a concern with diff-ing, `O` might be a better option.

Comment: This is exactly, what I have been looking for! `o` is most useful, I think :) Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I love using vimdiff to compare commits side by side:

`git difftool --tool=vimdiff commit_id_01 commit_id_02 path/to/file`